# transform.root returning wrong object Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, root, prefab

I have a button that's instantiated as a child of a prefab, when using transform.root it does not return the desired object.

`GameObject parentObj = this.transform.root.gameObject;`

that is the line in question

I have used Debug.Log to verify that, when instantiated, the name of the object is CityCenter(Clone), while transform.root.gameObject.name returns CityCenter, meaning it is getting the non instantiated version of the prefab instead of the object that is currently in scene.

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your object hierarchy form your editor, and you code where you instatiate the object.

Comment: Also "this.transform" it refers to the object that the script is attached to it. If you want to get the root of the instantiated object, you need to keep an instance of your instatiated object and then get the root of that object.